# Cordova won't run app in emulator

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

I have been seeing this error since I started using Cordova and it's really annoying because it happens randomly. When I run:

```
$ cordova emulate android
$ cordova run android --emulator
```

What I expect is then the app to pop up on the emulator screen, same way it works with Android Studio. However, the command keeps printing dots forever. This is the actual output:

```
$ ionic cordova emulate android Running app-scripts build: --platform android --target cordova [14:49:14]  build dev started ... [14:49:14]  clean started ... [14:49:14]  clean finished in 3 ms [14:49:14]  copy started ... [14:49:14]  deeplinks started ... [14:49:14]  deeplinks finished in 23 ms [14:49:14]  transpile started ... [14:49:17]  transpile finished in 3.65 s [14:49:17]  preprocess started ... [14:49:17]  preprocess finished in 1 ms [14:49:17]  webpack started ... [14:49:17]  copy finished in 3.79 s [14:49:23]  webpack finished in 5.63 s [14:49:23]  sass started ... Without `from` option PostCSS could generate wrong source map and will not find Browserslist config. Set it to CSS file path or to `undefined` to prevent this warning. [14:49:24]  sass finished in 1.19 s [14:49:24]  postprocess started ... [14:49:24]  postprocess finished in 6 ms [14:49:24]  lint started ... [14:49:24]  build dev finished in 10.62 s
> cordova emulate android Android Studio project detected

ANDROID_HOME=/Users/jgallaso/Library/Developer/Xamarin/android-sdk-macosx JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_101.jdk/Contents/Home studio Subproject Path: CordovaLib Subproject Path: app publishNonDefault is deprecated and has no effect anymore. All variants are now published.

The Task.leftShift(Closure) method has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 5.0. Please use Task.doLast(Action) instead.
        at build_ebvy0tyue1c6qxpdm1duui607.run(/Users/jgallaso/Projects/aerogear/apps/ionic-showcase-template/platforms/android/app/build.gradle:143) :CordovaLib:preBuild

UP-TO-DATE :CordovaLib:preDebugBuild

UP-TO-DATE :CordovaLib:compileDebugAidl

UP-TO-DATE :CordovaLib:compileDebugRenderscript  UP-TO-DATE :CordovaLib:checkDebugManifest  UP-TO-DATE :CordovaLib:generateDebugBuildConfig  UP-TO-DATE :CordovaLib:prepareLintJar

UP-TO-DATE :CordovaLib:generateDebugResValues  UP-TO-DATE

:CordovaLib:generateDebugResources  UP-TO-DATE :CordovaLib:packageDebugResources  UP-TO-DATE :CordovaLib:platformAttrExtractor UP-TO-DATE

:CordovaLib:processDebugManifest

UP-TO-DATE

:CordovaLib:processDebugResources

UP-TO-DATE :CordovaLib:generateDebugSources  UP-TO-DATE

:CordovaLib:javaPreCompileDebug

UP-TO-DATE :CordovaLib:compileDebugJavaWithJavac

UP-TO-DATE :CordovaLib:processDebugJavaRes

NO-SOURCE

:CordovaLib:transformClassesAndResourcesWithPrepareIntermediateJarsForDebug UP-TO-DATE

:app:preBuild

UP-TO-DATE

:app:preDebugBuild

UP-TO-DATE :app:compileDebugAidl

UP-TO-DATE :CordovaLib:packageDebugRenderscript  NO-SOURCE

:app:compileDebugRenderscript  UP-TO-DATE :app:checkDebugManifest  UP-TO-DATE :app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE :app:prepareLintJar

UP-TO-DATE

:app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE

:app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE :app:mergeDebugResources

UP-TO-DATE :app:createDebugCompatibleScreenManifests

UP-TO-DATE

:app:processDebugManifest

UP-TO-DATE

:app:splitsDiscoveryTaskDebug  UP-TO-DATE

:app:processDebugResources

UP-TO-DATE :app:generateDebugSources

UP-TO-DATE :app:javaPreCompileDebug

UP-TO-DATE

:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac  UP-TO-DATE :app:compileDebugNdk

NO-SOURCE :app:compileDebugSources  UP-TO-DATE :CordovaLib:mergeDebugShaders

UP-TO-DATE :CordovaLib:compileDebugShaders  UP-TO-DATE :CordovaLib:generateDebugAssets  UP-TO-DATE :CordovaLib:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE :app:mergeDebugShaders  UP-TO-DATE :app:compileDebugShaders  UP-TO-DATE :app:generateDebugAssets

UP-TO-DATE :app:mergeDebugAssets  UP-TO-DATE :app:transformClassesWithStackFramesFixerForDebug UP-TO-DATE :app:transformClassesWithDesugarForDebug

UP-TO-DATE :app:transformClassesWithDexBuilderForDebug  UP-TO-DATE :app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug UP-TO-DATE :app:transformDexArchiveWithDexMergerForDebug  UP-TO-DATE :CordovaLib:compileDebugNdk  NO-SOURCE :CordovaLib:mergeDebugJniLibFolders  UP-TO-DATE

:CordovaLib:transformNativeLibsWithMergeJniLibsForDebug  UP-TO-DATE :CordovaLib:transformNativeLibsWithIntermediateJniLibsForDebug  UP-TO-DATE :app:mergeDebugJniLibFolders  UP-TO-DATE :app:transformNativeLibsWithMergeJniLibsForDebug  UP-TO-DATE :app:processDebugJavaRes NO-SOURCE

:app:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug

UP-TO-DATE :app:validateSigningDebug

:app:packageDebug

UP-TO-DATE :app:assembleDebug UP-TO-DATE

:app:cdvBuildDebug

UP-TO-DATE

BUILD SUCCESSFUL  in 1s 46 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 45 up-to-date [14:49:28]  lint finished in 3.36 s Built the following apk(s):
        /Users/jgallaso/Projects/aerogear/apps/ionic-showcase-template/platforms/android/app/build/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk

ANDROID_HOME=/Users/jgallaso/Library/Developer/Xamarin/android-sdk-macosx JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_101.jdk/Contents/Home none Skipping build...

Built the following apk(s):
        /Users/jgallaso/Projects/aerogear/apps/ionic-showcase-template/platforms/android/app/build/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk

. 
.
. 
.
.
.
.
.
.
```

And as said, the dots continue forever.

Anybody has seen this before and knows how to fix it?

Comment: is an emulator showing up? did you try to wait more? (on my machine, android emulators take a **real long time** to show up and start)

Comment: When it shows up it normally doesn't take more than a couple of minutes. In this case, I have the emulator already running. When you wait that real long time, do you see these dots too? Perhaps I should wait that long too

Comment: it was just in case, some people are impatient if they don't know it's _quite_ slow. In my case I don't have this. There are dots that appear after the sentence "Waiting for emulator to boot", but you don't seem to have this text. Note that i am on old Cordova version (7.1.0), and that it didn't work when emulator was already opened, in here it hangs (without dots), had to let cordova open it for me to get something

Comment: Definitely waiting didn't work. I tried today again, after sleeping/waking up my laptop and first time it worked, after that the command is showing the infinite dots.

Answer (score 2):

Closing the simulator, wiping data, cold booting then running `cordova run android` again worked for me.